# how to fix "pharentesis in the textfield in flutter" on visual studio code?

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield

im not can do launcher this code, i have one error in a pharentesis, not speak much english. Help me.

@override

Widget build(BuildContext context) {

```
return Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    TextField(    //<=====error en este parentesis no se a que se debe
      decoration: InputDecoration (
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0,),
        hintText: inputText,
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(32.0)),
        ),
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(32.0)),
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.lightBlueAccent, width: 2.0),
        ),
        focusedBorder:  OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(32.0)),
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blueAccent, width: 2.0),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There may be more elements in one row. you can wrap TextField with Expanded and set flex

code snippet

```
return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: TextField(    //<=====error en este parentesis no se a que se debe
            decoration: InputDecoration (
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0,),
              hintText: inputText,
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(32.0)),
              ),
              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(32.0)),
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.lightBlueAccent, width: 2.0),
              ),
              focusedBorder:  OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(32.0)),
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blueAccent, width: 2.0),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          txtfield(),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}

class txtfield extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _txtfieldState createState() => _txtfieldState();
}

class _txtfieldState extends State<txtfield> {
  String inputText = 'this is hint';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: TextField(    //<=====error en este parentesis no se a que se debe
            decoration: InputDecoration (
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0,),
              hintText: inputText,
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(32.0)),
              ),
              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(32.0)),
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.lightBlueAccent, width: 2.0),
              ),
              focusedBorder:  OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(32.0)),
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blueAccent, width: 2.0),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image]